# Node, Express, Mongoose how to pass doc._id from a function to next() middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, middleware

Router:

`router.post('/add/someone', ctrl.func1, ctrl.func2);`

Controllers:

```
ctrl.func1 = function(req, res, next){
     // Save to db
     SomeSchemaModel(req.body.data).save(function(err, doc){
          if(!err){
               // assuming that theres no error
               // how can I pass the doc._id
               // to the next middleware
               // using the next() fucntion?
               next();
          }     
     }

}


ctrl.func2 = function(req, res){
     // do something with the _id
     // from the previous func1
}
```

Coz I looked it up from `ctrl.func2`'s **req** and **res** but there's no data from the previous `ctrl.func1`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach it on your `req` object

```
ctrl.func1 = function(req, res, next){
     // Save to db
     SomeSchemaModel(req.body.data).save(function(err, doc){
          if(!err){
               // assuming that theres no error
               // how can I pass the doc._id
               // to the next middleware
               // using the next() fucntion?
               req.docId = doc._id;
               next();
          }     
     }

}


ctrl.func2 = function(req, res){
     // do something with the _id
     // from the previous func1
     console.log(req.docId);
}
```

Comment: Is it wise to attach it on res? Or should I attach it on req? Does it matter?

Comment: I've just modified it. You should use `req`.

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot. If you could explain why use req that would be great! But thanks. :)

Comment: Now it seems to me you could use both, it doesn't really matter which one you choose.